# Python: Print rows into individual text files with columns separated by linebreak

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for being a python noob (with only basic programming skills)!

I have an excel file from which I need to export individual rows into single .text files, where the filename is that of a cell within a column. For example, I have an excel file like this:

```
Id   col1   col2   col3   col4
01   0      cat    34     k
02   1      dog    30     g
```

And I need the following:

- import the excel file, I've managed to do that;
- choose only rows where col1 contains 1;
- for each row, choose only col2, col3 to be printed into a text file where the data from col3 comes after a line break after the data from col2;
- name each file according to what's in ID.

So far, this is what I have:

```
import numpy as np #might not even be necessary?
import pandas as pd #might not even be necessary?

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    row_data = (df.iloc[i]['col2'], df.iloc[i]['col3'])
    row_data.to_csv('/home/laurall/Code/test2.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

This is probably simple, but I'm getting stuck in step 1 already :( can you help?

Comment: If you are stuck, you should share your approach with us

Comment: thanks @NicoHaase, I wrote this on my phone, bad idea. I've also added one of the things I tried, but this is very incomplete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
vals = [(1, 0, 'cat', 34, 'k'), (2, 1, 'dog', 30, 'g')]
df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['Id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])

subset = df.loc[df.col1 == 1] #subset for values equal to one in the col1

#loop through 
for i, r in subset.iterrows():
    for_write = '{} \n {}'.format(r.col2, r.col3)
    print(for_write)
    with open('{}.txt'.format(r.Id), 'w') as text_file:
        text_file.write(for_write)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Id" : ["01", "02"], "Col1" : [0,1 ], "Col2" : ["cat", "dog"], "Col3" : [34, 30], "Col4" : ["k", "g"]}

# Read the data from the xls file
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Choose only rows where col1 contains 1; for each row, choose only col2, col3 to be printed
filtered_df = df[["Id", "Col2", "Col3"]].loc[ df["Col1"]==1 ]

# Data from col3 comes after a line break after the data from col2; name each file according to what's in ID
for index, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
    with open(row["Id"] + ".csv", "w") as fout:
        print(row["Col2"], file = fout)
        print(row["Col3"], file = fout)
```

Note that in the answer we are assuming that there are unique Id's. If not, the files will get overwritten. To solve this use groupby(["Id"]) and then print the entire data to the file(then you will also have to change the format you expect as well).

Comment: Thank you, this works, too. Although I added `print('\n', file = fout)` inbetween to get the line breaks

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't write in python so often, so wanted to take the challenge. There are plenty of ways to do this obviously but my solution requires using openpyxl library. The documentation and installation is pretty simple and could be reached [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Here is the code, there are plenty of magic numbers but instructions lead me to use them:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range

wb = load_workbook('data.xlsx')

ws = wb.active
for a, row in enumerate(ws.rows):
    for b, cell in enumerate(row):
        if cell.value == 1 and b == 1: 
            f= open(str(ws.cell(row=a, column=1).value)+".txt","w+" )
            f.write(str(ws.cell(row=a, column=3).value)+"\n")
            f.write(str(ws.cell(row=a, column=4).value))
```